# Десериализация иерархического объекта

Tags: c#, десериализация

При сериализации и десериализации  я каждый класс помещал в разный файл и все было отлично. Но теперь необходимо в один файл записать сразу все три мои класса.

Код класса студентов:

```
class Students
{
    public int idСтуденты { get; set; }
    public string FIO { get; set; }
    public string Course { get; set; }
    public string specialty { get; set; }
    public string Date_of_Birth { get; set; }
    public string information_about_the_family { get; set; }
    public string id_group { get; set; }
    public string date_zach { get; set; }
    public int id_facul { get; set; }

    public Students(int idСтуденты, string FIO, string Course, string specialty, string Date_of_Birth, string information_about_the_family, string id_group, string date_zach, int id_facul)
    {
        this.idСтуденты = idСтуденты;
        this.FIO = FIO;
        this.Course = Course;
        this.specialty = specialty;
        this.Date_of_Birth = Date_of_Birth;
        this.information_about_the_family = information_about_the_family;
        this.id_group = id_group;
        this.date_zach = date_zach;
        this.id_facul = id_facul;
    }
}
```

Код класса факультетов:

```
class Faculty
{
    public int idФакультеты { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string number_of_places { get; set; }

    public Faculty() { }

    public Faculty(int idФакультеты, string name, string number_of_places)
    {
        this.idФакультеты = idФакультеты;
        this.name = name;
        this.number_of_places = number_of_places;
    }
}
```

Код класса группы:

```
class Groups
{
    public int idГруппы { get; set; }
    public string number_group { get; set; }
    public string amount_of_the_students_scholarship { get; set; }
    public string year_of_enrollment { get; set; }
    public string id_faculty { get; set; }

    public Groups(int idГруппы, string number_group, string amount_of_the_students_scholarship, string year_of_enrollment, string id_faculty)
    {
        this.idГруппы = idГруппы;
        this.number_group = number_group;
        this.amount_of_the_students_scholarship = amount_of_the_students_scholarship;
        this.year_of_enrollment = year_of_enrollment;
        this.id_faculty = id_faculty;
    }

    public Groups() { }
}
```

Все это я обернул в класс, назвал его обертка:

```
class Obertka
{
    public List<Students> students { get; set; }
    public List<Groups> groups { get; set; }
    public List<Faculty> faculty { get; set; }
}
```

При сериализации в json я использую следующий код:

```
string filename;
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;       
filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
ob.students = dl.GetStudents();
ob.groups = dl.GetGroups();
ob.faculty = dl.GetFacult();
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, 
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ob));
MessageBox.Show("Файл сохранен");
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно десериализовать сложный файл состоящий из нескольких классов?
В десериализации проблема в 1 строчке

```
Obertka lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Obertka>>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename));
dl.SetStudents(lists.students);
dl.SetGroups(lists.groups);
dl.SetFacult(lists.faculty);                  
text.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Export выполнен успешно");
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73024/discussion-on-question-by-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Будьте внимательнее, вы сериализуете объект типа `Obertka`, а пытаетесь десериализовать его в `List<Obertka>`, конечно, это не будет работать.

Исправьте строчку:

```
Obertka lists = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Obertka>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте XML сериализацию

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Path = "data.xml";
        Obertka obertka;
        try
        {
            obertka = Load();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Load " + ex.Message);
            obertka = Init();
        }
        //...
        // работа 
        //...
        Save(obertka);
    }

    static string Path { get; set; }

    public static void Save(Obertka adapter)
    {
        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Obertka));
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path))
        {
            s.Serialize(writer, adapter);
        }
    }

    public static Obertka Load()
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Obertka));
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);
            return (Obertka)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    private static Obertka Init()
    {
        Obertka ober = new Obertka();
        ober.students = new List<Students>();
        ober.groups = new List<Groups>();
        ober.faculty = new List<Faculty>();
        Console.WriteLine("Init new");
        return ober;
    }
```